# Is it possible for some achievements to require content that's behind an IAP on Google Play?

Tags: mobile, google-play-services, game-development, google-play-games, achievements

I am developing a game for mobile and want to distribute it with Google Play. The game contains achievements using the Google Play Achievements feature, but by design in order to unlock some of the achievements, the user will need to purchase the additional content the game has to offer, meaning the user won't be able to get 100% of achievements without buying some IAP.

It's not clear to  me if this behavior is acceptable based on [the guidelines from Google](https://developers.google.com/games/services/v1/checklist.).

I have tried to contact the support team but I think they misunderstood my concern as they stated that "making a purchase" is not an acceptable achievement trigger. I am not linking an achievement to the act of purchasing, but to some locked content.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not sure if it is against ToS, but [`this app`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fluik.USBSimulator2015&hl=en_US&gl=US) has an achievement that is directly tied to an in-app purchase. Unlocking the golden USB - which can only be done if you buy it with $.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Given how this is apparently clearly against the ToS, makes me think Google has quite a loose policy around this. At least my content is not directly tied to an-app purchase